# How to display an ObservableMap via JavaFX's TableView

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, observablecollection

Lately, I've been thinking about what's the best way to display an `ObservableMap` via JavaFX's `TableView`.

```
final ObservableList<Entry<K, V>> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(observableMap.entrySet());
tableView.setItems(observableList);
```

This obviously won't do the trick since changes to `observableMap` aren't reflected in the `TableView` because `ObservableMap#entrySet()` isn't observable, nor will edits committed to the `TableView` ever reach `observableMap` because `observableList` is just an `ObservableList` containing all entries from `observableMap` but it isn't backed by it.

There are two possible solutions coming to my mind which would provide this functionality.

1. A static utility method taking an `ObservableMap` and returning an `ObservableList`. To keep them synchronized, listeners are added to both, the map and the list, which automatically apply changes made in either one of them to the other.
2. Create a new type `MapBackedObservableList` implementing the `ObservableList` interface. When constructed an `ObservableMap` is stored as an attribute and all changes/requests are forwarded to it.

Implementing `ObservableList` seems to be much work, especially when thinking of all the other methods that have to be implemented too.

How would you approach this problem? This isn't the first time I'm trying to find a convenient way to dynamically display a map in a `TableView` and I'm sure that I'm not the only one having this problem, so I would like to finally write a piece of code which takes care of it.

Comment: The first thing you need to do, before you even think about implementation, is decide what you want the actual functionality to be here. Lists and Maps are fundamentally different structures. Do you really want the list to be modifiable? If so, what are you intending to do if an element is added to the list that has the same key as an existing element? How are you going to determine the order of elements in the list, given the map has no order associated with it? My hunch is that if you want to display the data in a `TableView`, a map was probably the wrong data structure to use to start with.

Comment: I want to display a tape (simple visual implementation of a Turing machine) which maps a state (enum) for some indices (integer). That means I have to be able to efficiently retrieve a state for every index and display all entries ordered by their index.

Comment: As far as I understand a map effectively is a list of entries where every key only exists once (I know that they are implemented differently, though). For my needs, it would be enough if the `ObservableList` couldn't be modified (besides the elements in the list/map of course) but would inform its listeners whenever an element is modified or added/removed to the `ObservableMap`.

Comment: Why do you need a `Map` for a tape (which is almost identical to constructed like a `List`)?

Comment: A map is effectively a *set* of entries, not a list. A list implies ordering. You could consider writing a subclass of [`ObservableListBase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableListBase.html) which wrapped and observed an observable map, but I still think it sounds like you shouldn't be starting with a map in the first place. (Surely what you described is simply a `List<State>`?)

Comment: But how can I retrieve a state of a certain index using a list? Isn't it bad to iterate through the whole list all the time?

Comment: The most commonly used list implementation in Java is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  Accessing an array list item by index via [`get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) is an [O(1) operation](http://bigocheatsheet.com), which is as efficient as you can get.

Comment: Yes of course, if the indices were 0, 1, 2, ... but they may be 24, 1049, 1052, ... even if this problem wasn't there this still wouldn't be a valid solution since I also want to be able to display maps with e.g. `String` as key type. The question was not if `Map` is the right data structure but how to dynamically display it in a `TableView`

Comment: @fabian The tape should be infinitely large. This means it has to "expand" itself when the left/right end is reached which isn't possible with a list (at least not in one direction). While I may be able to represent the tape using a different data structure, I still don't know how to conveniently display a map :P