# JavaFx, How to insert ObservableMap into TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, observable, tableview

I want to populate map values into tableview. I tried with observableList and its working fine. Whenever any value adds to list then table values are updates / refresh and shows new changes.

I want to do the same with map also. Whenever I adds any value to map table view needs to be refresh but it is not. I read so many articles but not able to solve this issue.

Article :

1. [Populate TableView with ObservableMap JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941980/populate-tableview-with-observablemap-javafx)
2. [How to display an ObservableMap via JavaFX's TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809784/how-to-display-an-observablemap-via-javafxs-tableview)

My Java code.

```
@Component
@FxmlView
public class MapExample {

    private static int i = 0;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Map.Entry<String, Person>> tableview;

    private ObservableMap<String, Person> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        System.out.println("Map Example !!");

        map.put("Vijay", new Person("Rahul", "Kakade"));

        map.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, Person>) change -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                System.out.println("If part !!");
                map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out
                        .println("Key :" + k + " Name :" + v.getFirstName() + " Last :" + v.getLastName()));
            } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("Else part !!");
                map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out
                        .println("Key :" + k + " Name :" + v.getFirstName() + " Last :" + v.getLastName()));
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        col.setCellValueFactory(
                (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getKey()));

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> col2 = new TableColumn<>("FirstName");
        col2.setCellValueFactory(
                (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getValue().getFirstName()));

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> col3 = new TableColumn<>("LastName");
        col3.setCellValueFactory(
                (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getValue().getLastName()));

        tableview.getColumns().add(col);
        tableview.getColumns().add(col2);
        tableview.getColumns().add(col3);

        tableview.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(map.entrySet()));

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        service.execute(() -> {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                map.put("Vijay", new Person("Rahul" + i++, "Kakade" + i));

                System.out.println(map.size());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Person Model :

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName = null;
    private String lastName = null;
    //getter and setter
}
```

I know there is some small mistake but not able to solve it. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `map.entrySet()` is not observable. So when you populate map with values entry set doesn't fire any notifications. You should create `ObservableList` and update it every time map is changed and use this list as tableview source

Comment: I tried this scenario also but not worked. Could you please share same example with changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way. But don't forget to populate map in FX thread.

```
@FXML 
private TableView<Map.Entry<? extends String,? extends Person>> table;

....

final ObservableMap<String, Person> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
final ObservableList<Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>> list=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

map.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, Person>) change -> list.setAll(change.getMap().entrySet()));

TableColumn<Map.Entry<? extends String,? extends Person>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Name");

...        

table.setItems(list);
```

Comment: Yes , It worked. Thanks a lot for your advise. I was tried almost 5 days now it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I made one mistake , I added map.entryset() into table which is not observable. Instead of map we need to add observablelist into table view.

Answer :

```
@Component
@FxmlView
public class MapExample {

    private static int i = 0;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>> tableview;

    private ObservableMap<String, Person> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    @FXML
    final ObservableList<Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        System.out.println("Map Example !!");

        map.put("Vijay", new Person("Rahul", "Kakade"));

        map.addListener((MapChangeListener<String, Person>) change -> {
            if (change.wasAdded()) {
                System.out.println("If part !!");
                map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out
                        .println("Key :" + k + " Name :" + v.getFirstName() + " Last :" + v.getLastName()));

                list.setAll(change.getMap().entrySet());
            } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
                System.out.println("Else part !!");
                map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out
                        .println("Key :" + k + " Name :" + v.getFirstName() + " Last :" + v.getLastName()));
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        col.setCellValueFactory((
                TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getKey()));

        TableColumn<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> col2 = new TableColumn<>("FirstName");
        col2.setCellValueFactory((
                TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getValue().getFirstName()));

        TableColumn<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> col3 = new TableColumn<>("LastName");
        col3.setCellValueFactory((
                TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Entry<? extends String, ? extends Person>, String> p) -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        p.getValue().getValue().getLastName()));

        tableview.getColumns().add(col);
        tableview.getColumns().add(col2);
        tableview.getColumns().add(col3);

        tableview.setItems(list);

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        service.execute(() -> {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                map.put("Vijay", new Person("Rahul" + i++, "Kakade" + i));

            }
        });

    }
}
```